# SQLite Group by case + aggregate

Tags: sqlite, group-by, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to group by aggregates from conditional statements but can't find the right way to do so.

One idea that comes to mind would be to CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE and query that, but in the case we can't create temporary tables, any ideas?

Here's current  query:

```
select
case when count( p.id) = 1 then "Just One Photo"
  when count(p.id) >1 and count(p.id) < 4 then "2 to 3 photos"
  when count(p.id) >3 and count(p.id) < 6 then "4 to 5 photos"
  when count(p.id) >5 then "More than 5 photos"
  end bin
,count(p.id) as photo_count
,ra
,----re----
from table1 b
inner join table2 p on b.key = p.key
```

**Here's the result:**

```
    +----------------+-------------+-------+--------------+
    | Aggregate      | photo_count | ra    | ----re----   |
    +----------------+-------------+-------+--------------+
    | Just One Photo |           1 |   4.0 |          166 |
    | Just One Photo |           1 |   4.0 |            6 |
    | Just One Photo |           1 |   2.0 |            5 |
    | 2 to 3 photos  |           3 |   2.0 |           10 |
    | Just One Photo |           1 |   1.0 |            4 |
    | Just One Photo |           1 |   2.0 |            6 |
    | Just One Photo |           1 |   4.5 |            6 |
    | 2 to 3 photos  |           2 |   4.5 |          282 |
    | Just One Photo |           1 |   4.0 |           91 |
    | Just One Photo |           1 |   3.5 |          340 |
```

**What I'm hoping for:**

```
    +----------------+-----------------+---------+--------------+
    | Aggregate      | avg(photo_coun) | avg(ra) | avg(re)---   |
    +----------------+-----------------+---------+--------------+
    | Just One Photo |             1.0 |     4.0 |          166 |
    | 2 to 3 photos  |             1.9 |     4.0 |            6 |
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the CREATE TABLE and INSERT SQL statements to enable the tables to be created and populated for providing a resolution as per [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)